# Paging, Limit Paging number php

Tags: php

How can I limit the paging number in php?

i mean like this, example:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

if number 3 clicked like this:

```
1 .. .. 4 5
```

or like this:

```
1 2 3 .. 5
```

or

```
.. 2 3 4 ..
```

so if too many paging numbers do not show all numbers

this my code:

```
$default_index = 0;
$default_batas = 2;
if(isset($_GET['batas']))
{
    $default_batas = $_GET['batas'];
}
if(isset($_GET['halaman']))
{
    $default_index = ($_GET['halaman']-1) * $default_batas;
}
$ambil_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id ASC Limit ".$default_index.", ".$default_batas);
$total_baris = mysql_num_rows(
        mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable")
    );
$nomor_paging = 1;
$html_paging = "<div>"; 
while($total_baris - $default_batas > 0)
{
    $html_paging .= "<center><div><a href='?halaman=".$nomor_paging."&batas=".$default_batas."'>".$nomor_paging."</a></div>";
    $nomor_paging++;
    $total_baris -= $default_batas;
}
if($total_baris > 0)
{
    $html_paging .= "<div><a href='?halaman=".$nomor_paging."&batas=".$default_batas."'>".$nomor_paging."</a></div></center>";
}
$html_paging .= "</div><br/>";
```

this the output code :

```
<?php echo $output_html?>
<?php echo $html_paging?>
```

Comment: [link](http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#.WwZw3nZ94YM) try using this

Comment: thanks sir for reply, i try but not works

Comment: Define your limit (how many pages is too much? I suggest odd number) and write function, which will calculate your pages. So if its 3 pages over your limit, you will show first page, last page and (limit-1)/2 pages before and after current page...

Comment: i confused for this sir, $("#content").html("Insert content"); // some ajax content loading... for insert content how to show data from database using my code above?